# What tasks are quantum computers good at that classical computers are not?

Tags: quantum-advantage

At this stage, a large number of theoretical proofs have made us vaguely aware of the particularity of quantum computers. *But what tasks are quantum computers good at that classical computers are not?* Are there concrete achievable cases to illustrate this, rather than theoretical derivations?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/135/55

Comment: also, did you include the [tag:qiskit] tag because you're asking specifically about things done/doable with qiskit? If so, please specify this in the body of the question as well