# On quantum and classical complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

Do we have an example of a task that provably consumes more time/memory in the case of a classical computer than a quantum one? For example, Shor's factorization is polynomial, while the classical deterministic factorization algorithms, as far as I know, are subexponential, but the polynomial algorithm is unknown, but also there is no proof that it exists, nor is there a converse proof. Please don't give "essentially quantum" problems that have no classical analogues, like bosonic sampling or something like that.

Comment: [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm#) requires provably fewer oracle queries when searching a completely unstructured database.

Comment: @Join the P.A.R.T.Y., welcome to QCSE.  Your question is a good one, but may versions of it have been asked on this site before.  I recommend you take a look at [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/135/are-there-problems-in-which-quantum-computers-are-known-to-provide-an-exponentia) along with some of the links therein.  If you can narrow your question more, it could also be helpful. Briefly, there are many *provable* separations, including both polynomial and exponential separations, for many practical problems, but in the "oracle" world.